# Is a dedicated graphics card still required for a professional Photoshop experience?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, hardware-recommendation, hardware

Five or so years ago not having a dedicated graphics card would make using any tool more sophisticated than a simple brush would cause Photoshop to turn into a slide show. Is this still the case in 2020 where integrated graphics have improved?

Comment: Any computer sold in the last 10 years can handle Photoshop. No clue what your experience was 5 years ago, but chances are it was *very* local issue which *could* have been resolved - or you were using something much, much, much older than merely 5 years ago.

Comment: Photoshop used gpu to accelerate and enable only certain things: while having everything on CPU could've tank the overal performance, you wouldn't see a drastic difference when, say, using the brush tool (brush engine is still on cpu). Modern integrated gpus support most of PS accelerated features.

Comment: See [Adobe Photoshop system requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html). Please note that tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Most nonintel integrated grapohics card is faster than 5 year old dedicated card. Just has worse memory options

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I guess a dedicated card is more useful for video editing, 3d work, and gaming.

Comment: It helps to know what your canvas size is resolution pixel wise, how many layers in your PSD document, and what your saved .PSD file size is in megabytes. These all factor in when slowing down the Photoshop experience. Also your computer from 5 years ago, what was the model number so we can track down its horsepower and compare that horsepower to what you can get today for $500. Gotta compare apples to apples here.